# Canon LBP 2900 printer on Debian

Tags: printing, canon, debian

If you have been struggling with this printer for some time following wrong tutorials, as I did, please refer to this WORKING tutorial:

https://underr.space/notes/it/it-0012.html 
(it's in Russian, but Google translates it quite well)

NB: You need to use CAPT drivers for 32 bit architecture, since drivers for 64 bit don't work.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this, but consider to separate your question - it should contain the question and the answer (with link to original Russian post).